# Download speeds extremely slow

Tags: wireless, internet, downloads, download-speed

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an Asus k55n laptop, and I have found that when I attempt to download the KDE desktop, I get download speeds that vary between less than 1kbs to nearly 1mbs, which is still a fraction of my 20mbs connection I only have this problem when using ubuntu, I get normal speeds while downloading in Windows.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: Here is the link: http://pastebin.com/NSjYVdXz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Then:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off' | sudo tee -a /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

Then set your wireless settings in network manager to match the images.[image: wireless settings 1] [image: wireless settings 2]
Then reboot.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept the answer so it will help other people. Thanks