# Download speed extremely slow Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, vmware

Am facing similar [issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/340231/328077) with my Wireless internet connection.

Ubuntu 14.04 as a guest OS on Windows 8.1 using VMware workstation 11.0

I get around 1000 kpbs(it's enough for me...) on Windows 8 while its "snailing" on virtual machine. [Here's the output of that script.](http://pastebin.com/sKgY2EYE)

I would love to see 1000 kpbs on my Ubuntu as well. It's hurting me a lot.

Comment: Based on your comments on Rita Martins answer, could you please edit and expand your question to indicate whether you mean updates are slow or what exactly you mean by "terminal download" and whether you are comparing speeds from the same site? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I was using VMWare player 6.03, booting Ubuntu 16.04 on a Windows 7 host. Both the wireless and wired connections were atrociously slow. Apt install of chromium-browser was going to take an hour just to fetch from the repo.

[This link](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2019058) provided a recommendation to check which Network Adapter you are using.

In VMWare under the Edit virtual machine settings -> Hardware tab -> Network Adapter, my Network connection mode was set to NAT. I changed this to Bridged, rebooted the vm and voila it only took a couple of minutes to install chromium-browser with apt.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Funnily enough, doing the opposite fixed it for me. Per default, it was in "Bridge (Automatic)". After changing it from bridge to NAT, it went from 1 to 1.5 Mbp/s to 450 Mbp/s.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a virtual machine before (virtualbox) and running an OS like that makes the guest OS very slow and you can't use the full potential. The best is have dual boot.

Comment: But the strange thing is web downloads works quite OKAY. Its the terminal download that's slow. Downloads are like forever...

Answer (score 0):

I personally run Windows in a VM under virtualbox using Ubuntu as a host and have no network issues whatsoever with lagging. I feel that the network handling under Linux is far superior to Windows (I think the vast number of apache webservers on the net means I'm not alone in thinking this). It sounds to me as if the requests aren't being passed through your Windows host rapidly enough. You may wish to check your networking configuration in your vm manager for possible misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was solved by turning off Windows Firewall. Obviously, this comes at a cost in terms of security.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem causing this was that i set the nameservers in the /etc/network/interfaces file, and it was not taking the ones provided by the dhcp on the wifi i connected. So i removed from this file the lines setting the arbitrary nameservers and now is working very fast.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)